# Assigning background color to div tag isn't changing background of elements inside div tag

Tags: css, html, background-color

I'm having difficulty assigning a background color to contents within a div tag.

Inside my html file I have...

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Guitar Gods</title>

    <link href="guitargods_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>

    <body>
       <div id="header">
       <h1>Guitar Gods</h1>
       <ul>
           <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Scales</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Videos</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">Exercises</a></li>
       </ul>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside my css file I have...

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

```
h1 {
    color: blue;
}
#header {
    background-color: black;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
#header ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    background-color: black;
}
#header ul li {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 5px;
    font:Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}
```

The h1 background is black but none of the items in my list have the assigned background color.

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  This seems to be really straight forward.

Comment: You'll need to track down the CSS that's causing the other elements to display differently. The code you posted [gives *everything* a black background](http://jsfiddle.net/8hhTA/), so we can hardly tell you what the problem is here. Have you tried using the developer toolbar in your browser of choice yet?

Comment: Also check that your markup is wellformed.

Comment: I added all the css.  I don't see anything that would prevent the background color from being applied.

Comment: there has to be some global property overriding it. can u place a fiddle with the prblm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to clear your floats (from the list items). One way to do this would be to add `overflow: hidden` to the `#header ul`.

Comment: Thank you that did it!  I'll have to do some research the the overflow property as I'm not familiar with it.  Thanks again.

Comment: I tried to give your comment a point but I'm still new to stackoverflow and don't have a reputation of 15 yet :(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :-) It'd be great if you could click the tick on my answer, to accept it. Take a look at http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/ for more on floats, which also mentions the overflow technique.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using firefox or chrome right click on the h1 element and inspect element.  You'll be able to see the css that are being applied to that tag.  You can always set the h1 background color to something else.

Comment: I added all of my html file as well.  So now everything has been included from my html and css files.